# Switch docker daemon from minikube back to docker desktop

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, minikube, docker-desktop

I recently changed the docker daemon from my local Docker Desktop to local minikube following these [instructions](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/pushing/#1-pushing-directly-to-the-in-cluster-docker-daemon-docker-env).

```
@FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('minikube -p minikube docker-env --shell cmd') DO @%i
```

After running some tests, I want to change it back to my previous setup. I already tried to change some environment variable but it did not succeeded.

```
SET DOCKER_HOST=tcp://127.0.0.1:2375
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the below command to get the list of Docker Hosts..

```
docker context ls
```

output will be something like below

```
NAME            DESCRIPTION                               DOCKER ENDPOINT                                   KUBERNETES ENDPOINT   ORCHESTRATOR
default *       Current DOCKER_HOST based configuration   unix:///var/run/docker.sock                                             swarm
desktop-linux                                             unix:///home/sc2302/.docker/desktop/docker.sock                         
rootless        Rootless mode                             unix:///run/user/1001/docker.sock
```

Now, from the output's, select the context you want to use.. ex: to switch to default context

```
docker context use default
```